# installing django on mavericks

Tags: python, django

I installed django using `pip install django==1.5.4` and I see it in the following directory:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django

however, when I type in `python` and then say `import django`, I see the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

Is there anything else I can/need to do? I tried to uninstall and reinstall several times! I can confirm that 2.7.5 is the version of python used on my system...

**EDIT**

I realized now that if I type in `python` it defaults to Python 2.7.5. But if I type in `python2` it defaults to 2.7.**6**.

They are installed in these locations:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 -- 2.7.5

/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 -- 2.7.6
```

Is there anyway to make the 2.7.6 version the default when I type in `python`? Seems like django is installed there....

Comment: Do `print sys.path` and see if there's a path to your `site-packages`..

Comment: In the command line, just do `which python` and make sure it is `python2.7`

Comment: Don't go this route - leave the Mavericks default python install alone, and use virtualenv to install whatever python envs you wish. Many SO examples. You will thank us later!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure that you have a link `/usr/bin/python` that points to your 2.7.5 version, so remove it and create other with the same name (`python`) to the version you want to use as default.

Nevertheless I recommends you to use virtualenvwrapper.